# Batch file: dealing with a parameter that can contain spaces and ampersand

Tags: batch-file

I've got a simple batch file that places the parameter it's called with into a text file:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set filename=%~n1
set pathname=%~p1
set letter=%~d1
>>path.txt echo %letter%%pathname%%filename%
```

(it does more, but this is sufficient to show the problem)

The parameter is a full path: 
C:\te st\file & name.xml

This batch file works as long as there's no & in the path name. But the above path results in `filename=file`
and the & is interpreted as an argument.

I tried using set `"filename=%~n1"`
but that results in

```
>>path.txt echo C:\te st\"file & name.xml"
```

which is incorrect. I can't get rid of the quotes. 
I tried:

```
>>path.txt echo %letter%%pathname%!filename!
```

but that results in

```
>>path.txt echo C:\te st\!filename!
```

How do I get the correct path in my text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "filename=%~n1"
set "pathname=%~p1"
set "letter=%~d1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
>>path.txt echo !letter!!pathname!!filename!
```

After assigning the content into variables, only delayed expansion should be used, because delayed expansion never changes or try to parse the content.

The `setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion` at the beginning ensures, that exclamation marks are preserved while assigning the arguments to variables.